# Need help using a bulk collect and for loop to provide the correct output

Tags: oracle, plsql

Other requirements:

- it must be an anonymous block of PL/SQL
- should use a bulk collect
- it should capture any m_codes that begin with M
- should sort by m_code

output should look like this (without the bulletpoints):

- Student m1: MAN
- Student m2: MIS
- Student m3: MKT
- Student m4: MPA

This is my current code, I feel like I am on the right track but I've just been stuck for too long (yes, I am a beginner and I kind of have no idea how the declares work in these instances). I am getting too many errors and am just stuck at this point.
One of the errors I keep getting is  "component 'COUNT' must be declared", but it does not let me do it any other way (that I know of). Is there a way I can only let it loop for the amount of m_codes that start with M?

```
DECLARE
TYPE  m_code_table   IS TABLE OF VARCHAR(3);

BEGIN
    SELECT m_code
    INTO m_code_table
    FROM Major
    WHERE m_code LIKE 'M%'
    ORDER BY m_code;
    
FOR i in 1..m_code_table.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Student major m' || i || ': ' || m_code(i));
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE
    TYPE m_code_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR(3); --definition of the type
    l_code_table m_code_table; -- declare local variable of type m_code_table
BEGIN
    SELECT m_code
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_code_table 
    FROM Major
    WHERE m_code LIKE 'M%'
    ORDER BY m_code;

    FOR i in 1..l_code_table.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Student major m' || i || ': ' || l_code_table(i));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

This should be the solution to your problem. First you need to define the type, then you need to create a local variable of this type. Then you can bulk collect into. In order for dbms_output to print to output, you need also command "set serveroutput on;".

Comment: This does seem to have gotten rid of most of my errors, so thank you so much for that. However, it is still giving me a "identifier 'MAJOR_CODE' must be declared" error. Do you know how I would do that? I thought it did not have to be declared if it already exists within the table in the "FROM" section.

Comment: This seems like your code is different than what you posted here. Without this information no one could help you solve problem. First, solve the problems that you have when selecting from database without PLSQL anonymous blocks. I think your select statement is not correct.